# how to set debuggable false in debug manifest

Tags: android, cordova, android-manifest, manifest

I'm updating an app in the Play Store, probably the first time in 2018 someone uploads debug APK and there is not a `.keystore` file so I had always updated this app with debugging APK, simply set `debuggable:false` in the manifest.

But now, after updating the Cordova and android platform, something went wrong. I have seen that also changing manifest (now situated in app/src/main instead of in android root), during the build the manifest generated under build/intermediates/merged_manifests/debug have `debuggable:true` attribute.
How could I force this attribute also in this manifest?

Comment: I can't understand how upload to play store without keystore. anyway check buildTypes in Gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

You should really consider building production builds and not debug builds, which will handle the manifest for you.

You should also consider building as a bundle now and let Android manage the app siging

```
 cordova build android --release -- --packageType=bundle
```

Read [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423) about signin